# Checking the binding of IP/MAC addresses for a device

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, icmp, mac

As a network administrator, assume I want to check IP/MAC binding of a certain device in my network to check if the binding has been changed or not (Since my network does not have DHCP server and static IP configuration is used). Which one I should use and what is the difference: `ICMP` or `PING`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by binding if you are not using DHCP.

If you want to look at the layer-3 to layer-2 resolution, you use ARP (Address *Resolution* Protocol) to *resolve* the layer-3 address to the layer-2 address.

ARP only works on the layer-2 domain. Layer-2 addresses, e.g. MAC addresses, are only relevant, or even seen, on the layer-2 LAN of the host. For example, you cannot get the layer-2 address of a host on a different layer-2 LAN (other side of a router hop).

---

FYI, ping uses ICMP echo request and echo reply.

Answer (score 0):

ICMP is a protocol used to report problems or issues with IP packets (or datagrams) on a network.
The most popular use of ICMP is to send ping packets to test the network connectivity of remote hosts. 
The network device generates an echo request packet that is sent to the destination device. 
Upon receiving the echo request, the destination device generates an echo reply. However the term binding is used when you have a DHCP server.